# how to get order day number on current date with weekend being passed on php?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to make a percentage chart that display how many employee who is absent who is not (means not recorded to absent_table), on current day on that month (example : today, is 27-07-2023, which means we are on 27 order day number). my algorythm about this is that, first we need to know the total absent best case until current day. so if I have 5 employee, then 5*27 is best case of total absent (it means all employee is absent and recorded on absent_table, this will be the divider. the rest I can handle it). my problem is that how to determine what order number day till current day, if weekend being passed. for example if today is 27 july 2023, then the ordered day number must 19, correct? (weekend for me means saturday and sunday)

to get current day is easy, i just do :

```
$current_day = date("d");
```

but i have to subtract it with total of weekend until that week. for me it's 4th week now, so :`4 * 2 = 8 total week`

so the formula become like this :

```
$ordered_day = (int)date("d") - $total_week; //I need to find this
```

I hope you guys understand. thank you.

EDIT :
Here's the final code look like, thanks to @Mpmp :

```
$total_weekdays = getWeekdaysBetweenDates(date("Y-m-01"), date("Y-m-d"));
$total_absent_best_case = $total_weekdays * $total_employee <-- of course, you fetch it from database
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand but

```
function getWeekdaysBetweenDates($date1, $date2, $holidays = [], $workDays = []) {
    $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date1);
    $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date2);
    $period = new DatePeriod(
        $startDate,
        new DateInterval('P1D'),
        $endDate->modify('+1 day')
    );

    $weekdays = 0;
    foreach ($period as $day) {
        $day_format = $day->format('d-m-Y');
        $in_holidays = in_array($day_format, $holidays);
        $in_work_days = in_array($day_format, $workDays);
        if (($day->format('N') < 6 && !$in_holidays) || $in_work_days) {
            $weekdays++;
        }
    }

    return $weekdays;
}

$date1 = '27-07-2023';
$date2 = '27-08-2023';
$holidays = ['28-07-2023']; // + 1 holiday
$workDays = ['30-07-2023']; // - 1 week day
$weekdaysBetweenDates = getWeekdaysBetweenDates($date1, $date2, $holidays, $workDays);
echo $weekdaysBetweenDates; // 22
```

Comment: it gave me this error "Call to a member function modify() on bool" what should I do?

Comment: @FajarAlamRahmatSidik most likely you entered the wrong date format, copy my code

Comment: I did copy all your code it still not work, but anyway I change the format to "Y-m-d" and it works. But the total weekend shows 21, it should be 19...

Comment: @FajarAlamRahmatSidik Are you seriously?

Comment: @FajarAlamRahmatSidik change `$date1 = '01-07-2023';
$date2 = '27-07-2023';`

Comment: well... the method is correct, i was wrong you were correct. I put the end date wrong, my mistake, thanks ahahaha.

Comment: so, i'm thinking about it and i ran across another problem... what if there is a holiday?. of course this holiday is (maybe) inputed by admin. how to subtract with holiday? any idea?